# How to use the def function to take player input and change a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to using Python (2.7) and I have come across a problem that I have tried to fix, but now I am resorting to asking anyone on this site to know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it. The problem I have is shown in this code...

```
num1 = '*'
num2 = '*'
num3 = '*'
num4 = '*'
num5 = '*'
num6 = '*'
num7 = '*'
num8 = '*'
num9 = '*'

print num1
print num2
print num3
print num4
print num5
print num6
print num7
print num8
print num9
print 

def position(x):
    if x == '1':
        num1 = 'X'
    elif x == '2':
        num2 = 'X'
    elif x == '3':
        num3 = 'X'
    elif x == '4':
        num4 = 'X'
    elif x == '5':
        num5 = 'X'
    elif x == '6':
        num6 = 'X'
    elif x == '7':
        num7 = 'X'
    elif x == '8':
        num8 = 'X'
    elif x == '9':
        num9 = 'X'

player_input = raw_input("Please enter a position: ")
position(player_input)

print num1
print num2
print num3
print num4
print num5
print num6
print num7
print num8
print num9
print
```

I have tried using global variable and I can confirm it works if I do not use the def function.

Thank you for your time
~Nate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python requires that inside of a function you explicitly mark the global variables.

```
def position(x):
    global num1
    if x == '1':
        num1 = 'X'
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! Helpful to know that I was using global wrong the entire time.